# Where to change the output of the Symfony2 ConsoleOutput?

Tags: php, symfony, logging, console-application

I am printing some lines on via the `ConsoleOuput`. I like to use the Table Helper, yet it uses StdOut by default and this seems to be hardcoded, as in the `\Symfony/Component/Console/Output/ConsoleOutput.php`, it says:

```
 * This class is a convenient wrapper around `StreamOutput`.
 *
 *     $output = new ConsoleOutput();
 *
 * This is equivalent to:
 *
 *     $output = new StreamOutput(fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
```

Within the project we have Log4Php, and are storing it to a file by changing the default output from stdout to a customized output.

Is there a way to change the output of the ConsoleOutput to something else than sdtout?

Because as of now, I can see the output in the command line in StdOut, yet when the php4log output is redirected to a file, the ConsoleOutput will still be in StdOut.

How can I merge those output together?

Answer (score 1):

Use `BufferedOutput()` instead of the `ConsoleOutput()`. It will store the message and you then can use the messages whereever you want them to.

Use the `$output->fetch()` method to get the message as a string. The string contain of all write operations you did on the `OutputInterface` before and the method call will also empty the buffer.

If you need to use it in a different logger, in your case a log4php instance, it would look something like:

```
$this->getLog4PhpLogger()
    ->info(
        $this->output->fetch()
    );
```